# Xpath How to get text content from childs except some tags

Tags: php, html, xpath, domdocument

I want to get text 1 and text 2 from this html code by Xpath.

```html
<div id="detailInfo" class="">
<h3 class=""><img src="/program/image/abc.gif" alt="ddd" width="92" height="23"></h3>

<p class=""><a href="http://link.html" target="_blank"><img alt="qvc_b.jpg" src="/image.jpg" width="300" height="50"></a></p>

<p class="">text 1<br>
text 2</p>

<p class=""><a href="http://link2.html">＞text 3</a></p>

<p class=""> <span style="color:#00a7ac; font-size:12px"><br>
------------------------------------------------------------------<br>
text 4<br>
text 5
------------------------------------------------------------------</span>
<span><br>
------------------------------------------------------------------<br>
text 6
------------------------------------------------------------------</span></p>
<!-- /detailInfo -->
</div>
```

The condition is get all text content direct from p childs of div and don't get text from "a" and "span" tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `text()` in this case with `normalize-space` so that it doesn't get with whitespaces:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html_string);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$elements = $xpath->query("//div/p/text()[normalize-space()]");
foreach($elements as $e) {
    echo $e->nodeValue . '<br/>';
}
```